# Camera intent is not opening camera in my poco f1 phone while running perfectly on other devices

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera

I am using following code to take pictures from camera. This code works perfectly on all devices but not on Xiomi Poco F1. It just blinks screen only. what is the problem please help me.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File dir = null;
            try {
                dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Folder/image.jpg");
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "app.example.testapp.fileprovider", dir);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, requestCodeCamera);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try This : https://github.com/Mariovc/ImagePicker

Comment: Presumably, there is a bug in the default camera app for that device. `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is for cases where you do not mind if there are problems like this and are willing to suggest to users another camera app to install. If that is insufficient, take the pictures yourself, probably using a library (e.g,. Google's CameraX, Fotoapparat, CameraKit-Android).

Comment: i also used CameraKit, that opens the camera perfectly